# Find skills that don't contains other skills in a table

Tags: google-sheets

(I'm French so, sorry for my English)

I'm actually creating a search tool for skills in the role playing game Pathfinder (the few who tried it will know why x'D) on Google sheets. I have on one sheet the DB with all the skills (I named it "Dons") and on the other sheet the filters and the filtered table.

To generate the filter, I use this kind of code:

**cell G14 :**

```
=CONCAT("select* where "; JOIN(" or "; QUERY(I2:I11; "select * where I is not null")))
```

I insert this code in this cell :

```
=IF(ISNA(G14); QUERY(Dons; "select *");QUERY(Dons;G14))
```

(I handle the case where the research gave no result; in this case I just show the entire list).

The row I is the row where I create the independent filter, for example, a filter that will show every skill which contains a specific term init will be like that:

```
=IF(F3;CONCAT("(C contains '"; H3; "'"; "or C contains '"; LOWER(H3); "')");"")
```

where F3 is the checkbox (apply the filter or not) and H3 the specified term to research.

(I hope I didn't loose you at this point xD)

My problem is as follow : I want to eliminate all the lines in the DB where the column C contains the full content of a cell in column A. (For example, if I have a skill which is named "Agilité dimensionnelle" (name is in column A) I don't want to have any skill that have "Agilité dimensionnelle" in the column C)

For that I tried to create a mixed filter with LOOKUP and QUERY but that doesn't work very well (it throw me an error):

```
=IF(F7;=ISNA(=LOOKUP(A;C;1;FALSE));"")
```

if someone as a hint on how to proceed, I would be very grateful!

Thanks a lot for read all this question and thanks already for the future responses!

Comment: Hey if you could share with me a google spreadsheet that has all of these formulas in it, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Yes of course, everyone should be able to see it at this link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17sRKCCUIkgPzCkIzLPvsxlP5eLlNeTT65jhjgNPq6Xw/edit?usp=sharing But it's all in French :/ All the formula are on the "Filtres" Page, in pink color.

Comment: Just to clarify. Cell A7 = `Agilité dimensionnelle`. So you want to exclude Row 8 because the value in Cell C8 = `Agilité dimensionnelle`.

Comment: Further clarification: Cell A5 = `Adepte de la matraque*` (not sure of the significance of the asterisk). However Row 6, Column C = `Adepte de la matraque, attaque sournoise +3d6`; i.e. it includes the value `Adepte de la matraque`. Would you wish to exclude Row 6 because of this match?

Comment: @Laura  Me again!! Perhaps this, or at least a variation, might work `=FILTER(BDD!A3:A,ISERROR(MATCH(BDD!C3:C,BDD!A3:A,0)))`. It returns the values in Column A that do not have an **exact match** in Column C. So, for example,  it excludes "Assaut dimensionnel" but not "Maître de la matraque*". Perhaps (possibly/beyond _my_ skills!) a wildcard might assist the later partial match.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Tedinoz ! (The asterisk is just an information for the players). In your examples with "Agilité dimensionnelle" and "Adepte de la matraque", I want to exclude the row you quoted. So the filter you show me is not exactly what I want but it's already a great step and I'm gonna work on it ! Thank you very much ! I will come later to explain my answer if I found it !